# input:text + textarea selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to do this:

```
$('input:text','textarea').focus(function () {
$(this).removeClass('wrong');
if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
$(this).val('');
}
```

But `$('input:text','textarea')` wont work as a selector. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `$('input:text, textarea')`